# FindFit is throwing a "Power: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered" error

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

I am attempting to fit a function with three free parameters to a set of data points. I get the error: "Power: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered."

The function in question is:

```
fit = 
  (Exp[-x* (a + b + c)]* 
    (-1 + Exp[(x* c)]* a* b* 
      (Exp[x* (a + b)]* (a - b) + Exp[x* (b + c)]* (b - c) + 
         Exp[x* (a + c)]* (-a + c)))) /
      ((a - b)* (a - c)* (b - c))
```

I believe this could be fixed by telling Mathematica to assume that `a`, `b`, and `c` are positive and `a != b != c`. However it seems that you can't give assumptions to `FindFit`. Any ideas on how to fix this or work around it?

Context:

```
data = 
  {{2, 1.00309*10^-6}, {7, 0.004429942}, {20, 
   1.10643*10^-10}, {40, 0.003376122}, {60, 0.012847188}, {85, 
   0.053338127}, {300, 0.226328628}}

FindFit[data, fit, {a, b, c}, x]
```

Amended to

```
FindFit[data, fit, {{a, .1}, {b, .11}, {c, .12}}, x]
```

which fixed the issue.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example needed to reproduce your problem. p.s. `e` is not `E`.

Comment: Try giving `FindFit` unequal initial values of `{a,b,c}` by specifying the parameters as '{{a,1}, {b,2}, {c,3}}`.  Some sets of unequal constants may work better than others.

Comment: Please change the title to something that resembles the question (or justify the relationship of the title to what is given in the text).

Comment: The online documentation does state that `FindFit` can use constraints: `FindFit[data,{expr,cons},pars,vars]`.  However, one can't use `!=` in the constraints.  Your best bet is to use the suggestion by @LouisB.

Comment: Thanks guys, the initial values fixed the 1/0 errors.

Comment: I hope you have more data than just 7 points to estimate 4 parameters ($a$, $b$, $c$, and $\sigma^2$).  Even then it's not a great fit and the last data point (`{300, 0.226328628}`) is highly influential.

Comment: Better that `FindFit` throw an exception than `FindException` throw a fit...